# Finding missing entries - R

Tags: r

I have a list of 5509820 obs in df1 that have addresses etc. To run them through a separate program, I had to split them out into 6 files, of up to 1 mil obs each, run them through the program, and then piece them back together in R.

I'm missing 80 rows. I did give the file a ID number before I split them:

```
df_combined<- tibble::rowid_to_column(df_combined, "ID")
```

Which has carried through. So I need to find a way to look through the df I have now with 80 fewer rows, and figure out which ones I'm missing so I can figure out which ones I've dropped. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `anti_join(df1, df2, by = "id")` from `dplyr` to return rows in df2 whose ids are not in df1's ids.

Comment: Welp, that was unbelievably perfect for what I needed, thanks!